# How to replicate code changes across multiple AWS instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have a load balanced setup in AWS with two instances. We do pretty frequent code updates, utilizing SVN. I need to know how easy it is to update the code changes across all the instances in our cluster. Can we simply do 'snapshots' and create new volumes each time for the instances?...or?...

Comment: Which language are you using? Take a look at AWS Elastic Beanstalk, I'm using it and it replicates your code automatically into all the servers of the load balancer with a single git push action (Note that it doesn't work with SVN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not do updates via EBS snapshots. Think of EBS volumes as a hard disk - you would not change your harddisk if you have an update for your software.

As you have your code in a version control system, code updates should be quite simple like logging in to your (multiple) servers and doing a `git pull` or `svn update`. This should fetch the latest code files from your servers. Depending on the type of application you would have to do some other tasks afterwards, running build scripts, emptying cache etc.

The problem is that this kind of setup does not scale well. If you have *n* servers, you will have to login and do this command *n* times. Therefore it makes sense to look into some remote management tools that you can use in one step. With a lot of these tools, you also get a complete configuration management stack: you define a set of recipes or tasks (like installed packages, configuration files, fetch the latest code, necessary build steps) for each of your servers, and when you boot up a new server it fetches the lastest version of its configuration and installs itself.

Popular configuration management tools include [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) or [Salt](http://saltstack.org/). Both tools have remote execution included which should make your task to publish your code base easier, you would only have to fire one command on your master server and it automatically executes this task on all its minions / slave servers.

Comment: Are there any good tutorials for a extremely BEGINNER person using github and ec2? I have a private repo created, just not sure of how to exactly perform the said 'git pull' to grab the code updates and put them on the instance

Comment: Have a look here - if you play with git for some time, you will quickly get used to the workflow: http://sixrevisions.com/resources/git-tutorials-beginners/